# MFC/wxWidgets MDI Child Window has Older Border Style

Tags: c++, mfc, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets to create an "MDI Child Window" inside a frame, however the child window has an older looking border style.

Is there any way to get the child's style to be the same as the parent's? I don't mind making MFC calls if necessary.

I mentioned wxWidgets AND MFC in the title because I feel this is more of a MFC issue than a wxWidgets one, but felt it necessary to mention that I am using wxWidgets.

The class of the child frame in wxWidgets is simply a wxMDIChildFrame, inside a wxMDIClientWindow, inside a wxMDIParentFrame, if it helps.

[image]

Comment: are you making a mix application with MFC? If not - can you post the "vanilla" MFC screenshot to compare?

Comment: A 'pure MFC' MDI application gives the same border style for MDI child windows (at least, in my projects, it does). Using VS2019, Windows 10, I see much the same styles as in your screenshot.

Comment: Apparently you can't. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016180/how-to-get-mdi-window-title-bars-on-windows-10-with-a-modern-look and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610613/why-arent-my-mdi-child-forms-showing-a-shadow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMDIChildWnd look & feel on Windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297775/cmdichildwnd-look-feel-on-windows-10)